Is it possible to select a different AMI version?
I need to run Rocky Linux 8.6 on AWS (or any other rhel-8.6 compatible). I could only find images with additional support by third parties, but this support doubles the vm price. Free I can only find Rocky Linux 8 (Official), with Latest version resf-rl8-20231119, which is Rocky 8.9. On the details page there is also this information:
Operating systems
Other 8.9.20231119
Other 8.8.20230518
Other 8.7.20230215.0
Other 8.6.20220515

Is it possible to select the older version of the AMI? And how much can I trust this AMI will not be deleted?

No, previous minor versions of EL are not supported. The responsible thing to do for new deployments and test environments is the most recent minor version with its security updates.
Regardless of which cloud you use, RHEL has worked like that for a long time. A minor version is current for about six months. Even when you pay for the privilege of staying on the previous version, with RHEL Extended Update Support or maybe alternatives like TuxCare, that only buys you a year or two. As of now in late 2024, EUS for 8.6 is almost gone.
Maintaining this general purpose operating system takes multiple patch cycles a year. It is a stable distro, so these will not change much, even to the point of ABI compatibility. But updates are required, freezing a minor version indefinitely is not an option.
If you thought the extended support was expensive, try hiring a service to custom maintain EL 8.6 for you. This effort would be better spent getting vendors and developers to accept that EL 8 means updated EL 8 not some minor version.
Once you are running a given instance template, you can copy it as a custom template, or for backup.  For deployment and recovery, you still need a patch strategy.
